# Studio Monitor's Cone not making sound after playing loud music through it

Tags: audio, hardware, monitors, studio-monitors

I was playing some very loud pop music through a studio monitor (ADAM A8X), and after about 5 seconds the sound stopped coming out of the cone and only came through the speaker. After shutting it off for a few minutes and trying again, no sound was coming from the cone. I assume I broke something, but don't know where to start in terms of fixing it. Any advice?

Comment: Next step is a specialist repair shop. We can't tell from here whether you blew a fuse [or if it even has them] melted a coil or blew an amp. Adam's web site makes no mention of overload protection, which I would have almost expected on something in this price range.